# My page doesn't load all the elements when using protractor. Manually it does

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have the next issue, hope you can help me.

I'm automating some tests, so I'm using protractor to do it. The problem is that the script is executed well, but the page that I'm testing doesn't load all the elements. Not all is empty, but it hasn't all the items it suppose to have.

Another clue is that I can load all the page properly when I do it manually. Putting the URL in the browser by my hand.

Does anybody know what can the problem be?

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't load all the elements`? is your script not waiting for the page to be completely loaded?

Comment: well, keeping it simple, my page has 1 div with 3 tables inside, 1 nav bar, 3 buttons(export excel, print, fullscreen). After the driver.get(), my page only gets the navbar and the buttons, the div is missing. I put a wait() for that div to appears but it never does. My script waits, the console tells me that is waiting. When I put the URL by my hand on the browser, all the elements are well loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have not idea why, if some one know please tell me. I found a solution:

*When I use: browser.get("url") - the issue is present.

*If I use: browser.driver.get("url") - The page loads well.

Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Thanks any way :)

Comment: Not a solution :'(    The reason is that browser.driver.get() is for non-angular pages. and the mine is angular